# Can try and catch be in different (but nested) macros?

Tags: clojure, macros, try-catch

The `try` is in one macro, the `catch` in a second one that is called by the first. How to get the following to work?

```
(defmacro catch-me []
  `(catch ~'Exception ~'ex
     true))

(defmacro try-me []
  `(try (+ 4 3)
        (catch-me)))
```

Expanding `try-me` looks good:

```
(clojure.walk/macroexpand-all '(try-me))
```

yields

```
(try (clojure.core/+ 4 3) (catch Exception ex true))
```

but calling (try-me) yields:

```
"Unable to resolve symbol: catch in this context",
```

which, BTW, is also the message you would get in the REPL when using catch when not in a try.

UPDATE:

This is how I can get it to work (thanks, @Barmar), here you can see the actual context of my code:

```
(defmacro try-me [& body]
  `(try
     ~@body
     ~@(for [[e msg] [[com.mongodb.MongoException$Network "Database unreachable."]
                      [com.mongodb.MongoException "Database problem."]
                      [Exception "Unknown error."]]]
         `(catch ~e ~'ex
            (common/site-layout
             [:div {:id "errormessage"}
              [:p ~msg]
              [:p "Error is: " ~e]
              [:p "Message is " ~'ex]])))))
```

but this is what I was hoping for (using a separate macro `catch-me`):

```
(defmacro try-me [& body]
  `(try
     ~@body
     (catch-me com.mongodb.MongoException$Network "Database unreachable.")
     (catch-me com.mongodb.MongoException "Database problem.")
     (catch-me Exception "Unknown error.")))
```

I think this would be easier to write / maintain.

Any ideas? I need syntax-quoting because I am passing parameters, that is why unfortunately Arthur's answer cannot be applied (or can it somehow?), but I didn't post my actual context until just now.

Comment: My current guess is that (catch-me) is expanded first, before it is clear that it is inside a try. Is that it? How to fight that?

Comment: Macros are only expanded in places where an expression would be evaluated normally. The `catch` subforms are not expressions that get evaluated, they're part of the syntax of `try`.

Comment: I currently still consider this question as unanswered. It is baffling why Arthur's example works but one using syntax quoting does not, and, that macroexpand-all shows a working macro expansion but a direct call to it fails with an error. Thanks to Barmar for the workaround. Any other ideas, anyone?

Answer (score 5):

The reason you get that error is because the syntax for `try` is:

```
(try expr* catch-clause* finally-clause?)
```

This means that there can be any number of *expr* forms before the *catch* and *finally* clauses. `try` scans the `expr`s until it finds one that begins with `catch` or `finally`. It does this *before* expanding any macros, since it's just trying to figure out where the exprs and and the catch/finally clauses begin. It collects all the `catch` and `finally` clauses and establishes the appropriate error handling environment for them.

Once it does this, it executes all the `expr` forms normally. So it expands their macros, and then executes them. But `catch` is not a function or special form, it's just something that `try` looks for in the earlier step. So when it's executed normally, you get the same error as when you type it into the REPL.

What you should probably do is write a macro that you wrape around your entire code that expands into the `try`/`catch` expression that you want. Without an example of what you're trying to accomplish, it's hard to give a specific answer.

Comment: I see what you are saying, but have the feeling that the problem arises from the `catch` being evaluated too soon and not too late, which is how I read your answer, wouldn't you agree? That would also explain why the answer by @arthur (I agree with him that it is not the prettiest solution) works: the `catch` is spliced in but not yet evaluated. I am working on getting that happening and still using syntax-quoting :-) I did follow up on your suggestion and have wrapped all my code in one macro, will either post that or, if I find it, a niftier solution :-)

Comment: The problem is that `catch` should never be evaluated at all, there is no "too soon". `catch` and `finally` are not real operators, even though they're written like they are. The compiler looks for them literally when scanning the body of `try`.

Comment: Right, but I would think that during macro processing, the try is at first just 'pasted' (quoted), which would explain why @Arthur's solution works (even if not for me)? In any case, I find it confusing that `macroexpand-all` shows a working expansion but it nevertheless does not work.

Comment: I was going to say it's a bug in `macroexpand-all`, but it seems unfixable. Anything in the body of the `try` that doesn't begin with `catch` or `finally` has to be macroexpanded. So when it's done, there's no way to tell that these `catch` subexpressions were not in the original form, which is where they need to be to be recognized. It's unfortunate that the syntax of `try` is ambiguous like this.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, it just doesn't seem right to me, it also contradicts the fact that @Arthur's example works, no?

Comment: I'm not sure why Arthur's example work. Since he's unquoting `(catch-me)` it should try to evaluate it, which shouldn't work. It would work if he defined `catch-me` as a function rather than a macro; then the result of the function would be substituted into the `try` form. Since this happens before evaluating the `try`, it sees the literal `catch` and everything works.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is YES, though nesting macros with special forms can lead to some double-quoting headaches like this one. It is necessarily to prevent the symbols from being evaluated at both levels of expansion:

```
user> (defmacro catch-me []                                   
          '(list 'catch 'Exception 'ex  
                       'true))

user> (defmacro try-me []
    `(try (+ 4 3)              
                  ~(catch-me)))
#'user/try-me

user> (try-me)
7
```

and to see that it catches the exception as well:

```
user> (defmacro try-me []
    `(try (/ 4 0)
              ~(catch-me)))
#'user/try-me
user> (try-me)
true
```

Comment: Since your suggestion and `(clojure.walk/macroexpand-all '(try-me))` both work I am still trying to find one that uses syntax-quoting. I will post if I find it or just follow up on @Barmar's suggestion.